# Problem formatting 4-digit integers with thousands separator

Tags: swift, formatting

```
print(String(format: "%d", locale: Locale.current, 33600))

//prints 33.600

print(String(format: "%d", locale: Locale.current, 3360))

//prints 3360 without thousands separator
```

Same issue using NumberFormatter.

Comment: This works fine with a Swedish locale, what is your locale?

Comment: The problem seems limited to Spain. I have solved it with this code:

                    let locale: Locale = Locale(identifier: "eu")
                    print (String(format: "%d", locale: locale, score))

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the US, where the thousands separator is a comma, the following code:

```
print(String(format: "%d", locale: Locale.current, 33600))
print(String(format: "%d", locale: Locale.current, 3360))

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

print(formatter.string(from: 33600)!)
print(formatter.string(from: 3360)!)
```

Outputs:

```
33,600
3,360
33,600
3,360
```

So it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to be an ios bug for Spain. After reading your answer, I have changed the region of my iPhone to France, where the comma is also used as a thousands separator, and it is displayed correctly.